# Parse activity not showing up

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to use ParseUI in my applicaiton. I imported all the necessary libraries and made the build to work and even RUN works, BUT nothing shows up.
This is my 
**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.techiequickie.bharath.parsetest" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <activity
            android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <!-- For more options, see https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#ui-login -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity.PARSE_LOGIN_ENABLED"
                android:value="true"/>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity.PARSE_LOGIN_EMAIL_AS_USERNAME"
                android:value="true"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>



        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Login_activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login_activity">


        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomePage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home_page" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PlaceBet"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_place_bet" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NewBet"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_new_bet" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Account"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_account" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Listbets"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_listbets" >



        </activity>



    </application>


</manifest>
```

As you can see I want login activity to be the starting activity. This is the activity that has the ParseUI login code

**LoginActivity**

```
package com.techiequickie.bharath.parsetest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.parse.ui.ParseLoginBuilder;


public class Login_activity extends Activity  //implements Validator.ValidationListener
{




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ParseLoginBuilder builder = new ParseLoginBuilder(Login_activity.this);
        startActivityForResult(builder.build(), 0);

    }

}
```

When I run, no activity popsup

```
04-27 19:53:18.423: I/ActivityManager(764): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.techiequickie.bharath.parsetest/.MainActivity} from pid 4741
04-27 19:53:18.423: W/ActivityManager(764): Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.techiequickie.bharath.parsetest/.MainActivity } from null (pid=4741, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10325
```

After doing that

[image]

I am getting waiting for Debugger error

Comment: The log file says you tried to start the .MainActivity using a launcher Intent. Are you sure that your build scripts do not contain references to MainActivity being used as Launch activity? In other words: If you launch your app manually, do you get the same problem?

Comment: Yes you are right I tot so too, but cannot find where elese I would do that? Other than AndroidManifest.xml file I  mean

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: I am using Android Studio

Comment: Run->Edit Configurations->Android Applications->[YOUR APP]->Check that "Launch default Activity" is set

Comment: i edited and I am getting waiting for Debugger, btw I am using my phone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76360/discussion-between-mach-and-jackyboi).

Comment: Please give me a while...

Comment: hi, I am in chat and updated with progress

Answer (score -1):

add this to your LAUNCHER activity in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Have you seen the AndroidManifest.xml??

Comment: ParseLoginActivity.java class should be the launcher class right?

Answer (score -1):

Add this with in activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml and accordingly remove the same from LoginActivity.

```
  <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
```

Your activity will be seems like this:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <!-- For more options, see https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#ui-login -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity.PARSE_LOGIN_ENABLED"
                android:value="true"/>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity.PARSE_LOGIN_EMAIL_AS_USERNAME"
                android:value="true"/>
      <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Have you seen the AndroidManifest.xml??

Comment: Remove this from there.

Comment: In one application should have only one launcher activity. One app can not allowed multiple launcher activity

Comment: still the same.. nothing shows up... i edited my original question to reflect the updated manifest file